# Why am i getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayQuestion' of undefined?

Tags: javascript

I tried to find the answer to my problem but really non of the answers i found here helped me. I know this is commonly asked question but i couldn't find right answer.
Here is my code:

```
    //Constructor for creating questions
function Question(question, answers, correct) {
    this.question = question;
    this.answers = answers;
    this.correct = correct;
}
//Creating question
var q1 = Question('Is JavaScript the best programming lenguage?', ['Yes', 'No'], 0);
var q2 = Question('What is the name of your teacher?', ['Mike', 'John', 'Jonas'], 2);
var q3 = Question('How would you best describe coding?', ['Boring', 'Fun', 'Tedius', 'Hard'], 1);

//Displaying question and answers
Question.prototype.displayQuestion = function(){

    console.log(this.question);

    for (var i = 0; i < this.answers.length; i++) {
        console.log(i + '. ' + this.answers[i]);
    }
}


//Choosing random question
var questions = [q1, q2, q3];
var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length);

questions[n].displayQuestion();
```

I keep getting 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayQuestion' of undefined
    at challenge.js:27
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `new Question` ?   ps, to prevent accidentally calling a constructor type function, add this as your first line -> `'use strict'; if (!this) throw new Error("Call with new");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling `Question(...)` but you really mean to call `new Question(...)`.

When you call `Question(...)` without `new`, it returns `undefined` because it has no `return` value (also, `this` is `window` instead of a new object).

When you use `new`, `this` is set to a newly-created object, and if there's no `return` value, the `new Question` call returns the newly-created `this` object. That's certainly what you expect your code to do.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot

Answer (score 6):

Use `new` keyword before `Question()`